# How to calculate average from text file without numpy or pandas

Tags: python, average, standard-library

Here is the code I used to calculate average with numpy and pandas

```py
def calc_average_books_stock():
    
  text_file = open('book_data_file.txt')
    
  values = []
    
  for index,data in df.iterrows():
        
    if int(data['STOCK']) > 0:
            
      values.append(data['COST?'])
    
      avg = np.mean(values)
    
      print(f"Average Book in Stock: {round(avg, 2)}")
```

I would like to know if there was a way to this without numpy and pandas and just be able to do it with python's standard library

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html try statistics?

Answer (score 1):

*do it with python's standard library*
You might use `.mean` from `statistics` built-in module to calculate average, for example:

```
import statistics
values = [10, 30, 20]
avg = statistics.mean(values)
print(avg)
```

output:

```
20
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100 sure of where `df` is coming from, but if your file is in some kind of CSV format, you can replace the pandas with csv.

No need for any the numpy or statistics libraries -- the average is just the `sum()` divided by the count.

And I think your indentation is off for when you are calculating the mean.

```
import csv

def calc_average_books_stock():
    
  text_file = open('book_data_file.txt', 'r')

  reader = csv.DictReader(text_file)
    
  values = []
    
  for data in reader:
        
    if int(data['STOCK']) > 0:
            
      values.append(data['COST?'])
    
  avg = sum(values) / len(values)
    
  print(f"Average Book in Stock: {round(avg, 2)}")
```